# Azure VM backup/automation not working after restore

Tags: azure, azure-automation, azure-vm, azure-backup-vault

After the VM was restored (whole VM not disk), the backup stopped working in Recovery Service Vault. Also the Azure automation account that used to shutdown the VM, stopped working. How to fix it such that all restored VMs continues to work as the previous one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly note that if you restored a VM to the same resource group with the same name as the originally backed-up VM, backup continues on the VM after restore, else if you restored the VM to a different resource group or you specified a different name for the restored VM, you need to set up backup for the restored VM.